# Auth login with admin prefix not working

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, migrate

My app controller:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

var $uses = array('Header','SubHeader','User','UserGroup');
    //public $uses = array('Admin');

    public function beforeFilter() {

    }

    public function beforeRender() {

    }
   public function beforeSave($options = array()) 
                   {

                   }

    // Check Users Authorization 
    public function isAuthorized($type=array()) 
    {
            return true;
    }
}
```

My routes.php:

```
 Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'indexs', 'action' => 'index'));

        Router::connect('/admin', array('admin'=>true ,'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
```

My UsersController:

```
 var $name = 'Users';
    var $uses = array('Header','SubHeader','User','UserGroup');
    public $components = array('Session', 'Security', 'RequestHandler', 'Email', 'Cookie', 'Auth' => 
    array('authorize' => array('Controller'),
          'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
          'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'dashboards', 'action' => 'index'),
          'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
          'authError' => "You can't access that page.",
          'authenticate'=> array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'fields' => array('username' => 'username','password' => 'password')
            ))
          ));
```

admin_login:

```
 public function admin_login() {
        $this->layout = "admin";
       if($this->request->is('post')){
           //   echo $this->Auth->password($this->data['Users']['password']);
                    debug($this->request->data['Users']['password']);
                    debug($this->Auth->login());
                    if($this->Auth->login()){
                            //echo 'hkiiiii';   
                    $name = $this->Auth->user('username');
                    $sid = $this->Auth->user('id');
                    $this->Session->write('b', $name);
                    $this->Session->write('sid', $sid);

                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());

                }

            else{
                //echo 'hki';
                $this->Session->setFlash(__("Your email/password combination was incorrect.", true), 'default', array('class'=>'gagal'));
                $this->redirect($this->referer());


            }
        }
    }
```

I have problem to login using admin prefix.
I am using *cakephp 2.4.6*.
`debug($this->request->data['User']['password'])` is returning the correct password but 
`debug($this->Auth->login())` is returning false.

Answer (score 0):

Write the code in beforeFilter of app controller:

if (isset($this->request->params['admin'])) {

```
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'User';
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('scope' =>array('User.status' => Configure::read('App.Status.active'),'User.role_id' => Configure::read('App.Admin.role'))));
        $this->Auth->loginError = "Login failed. Invalid username or password";

        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'dashboard');
        $this->Auth->authError = 'You must login to view this information.';
        $this->Auth->autoRedirect = true;
        $this->Auth->allow('admin_login');


    }
```